# Easy_captcha auto refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Recently,I use `easy_captcha` (https://github.com/phatworx/easy_captcha) in my project.

I have a signup page ,and a captcha is placed in this page, when user enter a username,I will send  an `ajax post` request to vertify  if this username has been signuped before.

But when I submit the form,I was  told the captcha is out of date.

I find that,when I send a post request,the  captcha  will refresh,but why?what should I do ? I can't make the user manually refresh the captcha  again to submit the signup form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reload the captcha tag after your ajax request. Try reloading the captcha in the controller and passing it back when you submit your ajax request. You're essentially refreshing the captcha before you submit for real.

In your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  render :json =>{:captcha =>"<p>#{valid_captcha?(params[:captcha]) ? 'valid' : 'invalid' } captcha</p>"}
end
```

Then set the html to be

```
$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data['captcha'] );
});
```

Its hard to give a good example without code to go on though